struct i2c_driver initialization of ‘int (*)(struct i2c_client *)’ from incompatible pointer type Kernel Device driver
I am trying to write a driver for my i2с device. But I got a dead end problem, which I could not solve with the help of Google for several days.
In general, I simplified the code to a minimum to understand where exactly the error is.
#include <linux/i2c.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

static int my_i2c_probe(struct i2c_client *client, const struct i2c_device_id *id)
{
    pr_info("Probe function called\n");
    // Add your probe implementation here
    return 0; // Return 0 on success
}

static int my_i2c_remove(struct i2c_client *client)
{
    pr_info("Remove function called\n");
    // Add your remove implementation here
    return 0; // Return 0 on success
}

static const struct i2c_device_id my_id_table[] = {
    { "my_i2c_device", 0 },
    { }
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(i2c, my_id_table);

static struct i2c_driver my_i2c_driver = {
    .driver = {
        .name = "my_i2c_driver",
        .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    },
    .probe = my_i2c_probe,
    .remove = my_i2c_remove,
    .id_table = my_id_table,
};

static int __init my_init(void)
{
    return i2c_add_driver(&my_i2c_driver);
}

static void __exit my_exit(void)
{
    i2c_del_driver(&my_i2c_driver);
}

module_init(my_init);
module_exit(my_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Your Name");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Sample I2C Driver");

The constant error I get:
sudo make 
make -C /lib/modules/6.6.37-v8+/build M=/home/pi/ForestBox/driver modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/linux-4251c6ff2aa870ca9782abc0ecdf60eac3ba22ab'
  CC [M]  /home/pi/ForestBox/driver/RTC_PCF_Driver.o
/home/pi/ForestBox/driver/RTC_PCF_Driver.c:29:14: error: initialization of ‘int (*)(struct i2c_client *)’ from incompatible pointer type ‘int (*)(struct i2c_client *, const struct i2c_device_id *)’ [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
   29 |     .probe = my_i2c_probe,
      |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/pi/ForestBox/driver/RTC_PCF_Driver.c:29:14: note: (near initialization for ‘my_i2c_driver.probe’)
/home/pi/ForestBox/driver/RTC_PCF_Driver.c:30:15: error: initialization of ‘void (*)(struct i2c_client *)’ from incompatible pointer type ‘int (*)(struct i2c_client *)’ [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
   30 |     .remove = my_i2c_remove,
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/pi/ForestBox/driver/RTC_PCF_Driver.c:30:15: note: (near initialization for ‘my_i2c_driver.remove’)
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /home/pi/ForestBox/driver/RTC_PCF_Driver.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/home/pi/linux-4251c6ff2aa870ca9782abc0ecdf60eac3ba22ab/Makefile:1921: /home/pi/ForestBox/driver] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:234: __sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/linux-4251c6ff2aa870ca9782abc0ecdf60eac3ba22ab'
make: *** [Makefile:5: all] Error 2

Here is the kernel version
$ uname -r
6.6.37-v8+

GCC version
$ gcc --version
gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

I understand what the error is about, and that the signatures must match. and it seems to me that they are the same.
I tried to do the same on another fresh OS but same device and got the same error.
I suspect there is a bug with the versions, but how can I check?

What is unclear for example with this error message "error: initialization of ‘void ( * )(struct i2c_client *)’ from incompatible pointer type ‘int ( * )(struct i2c_client *)"? Do you see the difference between the pointer types?

According to the error message the functions need to be static int my_i2c_probe(struct i2c_client *client) and static void my_i2c_remove(struct i2c_client *client) to be compatible.

My main problem is with the probe. that's how I saw the error from remove. this is not a problem. I tried the probe without the 2nd argument. and it works. but why? does he not need an ID?  It turned out to be a stupid write-up, as other people sometimes do, although I clearly tried to compare it

If I answered your question, please accept that. You need to tick on the respective checkbox.

The original driver was probably written for an older kernel version. The kernel API is not stable between kernel versions except within a "stable" kernel series.

The return type of the i2c driver remove handler was changed from int to void in kernel 6.1 by commit ed5c2f5fd10d. The 2nd parameter of the probe handler was removed in kernel 6.3 by commit 03c835f498b5 after all in-tree drivers were changed to use probe_new, which was removed in 6.6 after drivers were changed again to use the updated probe.

There are several issues with your code of diffent severity. I put below in a chronological order (from what the older vanilla kernels get, to newer ones).

Owner of the module is not needed as it is assigned via macro. At the same time you may use module_i2c_driver() macro instead of open coding it (as ->init() and ->exit() functions).

For a long time kernel has two functions for the —>probe(), one of which was called ->probe_new() until recently Uwe Kleine-König have decided to finish the 10 or so years old job, i.e. convert all users to use new variant, which has one argument less. Note, you still able to get an ID from the table, however in new code it’s considered redundant as all properties should be gotten via the respective firmware interface: ACPI, Device Tree, or software nodes. (Note, .driver_data can be retrieved also in an agnostic way.)

He hadn’t stopped on that and continued to drop unnecessary returned codes from the ->remove() functions by using the same approach: 1) creating a new prototype; 2) converting all users; 3) renaming back; 4) removing a temporary prototype.

He doesn’t stop yet as a new coming (actually in progress) change is to convert .driver_data member of the ID table from kernel_ulong_t to const void *. It will be done within a couple of kernel releases I believe.


Summarized that, you need to: 1) drop the last parameter in ->probe(); 2) drop the return statement and convert to void your ->remove() implementation; 3) drop the , 0 part in the ID table; 4) drop the .owner assignment; 5) use module_i2c_driver() macro.
P.S. There are tons of examples of the I2C device drivers in the kernel, especially the newest ones under drivers/iio, you may find them roughly using this command git log --no-merges --oneline --grep module_i2c_driver -- drivers/iio. Or online: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.10/A/ident/module_i2c_driver.

As a bit of a time line, module_i2c_driver was added in 3.3, probe_new was added in 4.10, the return type of remove was changed to void in 6.1, probe was changed to match probe_new in 6.3, and probe_new was removed in 6.6.

It doesn't look like kernel_ulong_t driver_data; is being converted. Rather it is being placed in an anonymous union with const void *data; so drivers can choose to use a pointer or an integer without any messy type casting.

@IanAbbott, you should read what I said in the answer carefully. It is not converted yet, but it will be at some point, rather sooner than later (in opposite to the .probe_new case).

Yes, I know its only RFC at the moment. But the RFC I have seen is not proposing to get rid of kernel_ulong_t driver_data because that would just substitute one set of ugly type casts for another set of ugly type casts.
